# Could Not Link Assemblies in Xamarin iOS when build a project in Mac

Tags: c#

Error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of 'GYBMobile.iOS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (MT2001) (GYBMobile.iOS)

Comment: Hi @Muntazir Alam, could you please add more information to your question?

Comment: What type of more information

Answer (score 0):

This is probable reason:

1. Add -v -v -v -v in **iOS Build => addition mtouch arguments**
2. build the app and check the build output
3. Check packages.config file and findout the missing package.
4. Add it from nuget and rebuild the app

Hope this helps